# Open, Edit and Re-Save a CSV file

Tags: csv, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a .CSV like file that I would like to do one of the two things to it.

The data in the file looks like this:

```
"BRANCH","CARD","BILL_TYPE","AUTH_CODE","INVOICE","UNIT","EMP_NUM","TRIP","TRAILER","HUB/SPEED","VEH_LICENSE","DRIVER","DATE","TIME","CHAIN","IN_NETWORK","TS#","TS_NAME","TS_CITY","TS_STATE","PPG","NET_PPG","FUEL_GALS","FUEL_AMT","RFR_GALS","RFR_AMT","CASH","MISC","INV_TOTAL","FEE","DISC","INV_BALANCE",1.00,1.00,"E","004ACS","02812","365","-","-","0",0.00,"-","JOHN S  ",11/4/2013,"16:18:49E","IC","N",3257.00,"IRVING HOULTON","HOULTON","ME",3.95,3.95,121.57,480.08,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,480.08,1.50,0.00,481.58
"BRANCH","CARD","BILL_TYPE","AUTH_CODE","INVOICE","UNIT","EMP_NUM","TRIP","TRAILER","HUB/SPEED","VEH_LICENSE","DRIVER","DATE","TIME","CHAIN","IN_NETWORK","TS#","TS_NAME","TS_CITY","TS_STATE","PPG","NET_PPG","FUEL_GALS","FUEL_AMT","RFR_GALS","RFR_AMT","CASH","MISC","INV_TOTAL","FEE","DISC","INV_BALANCE",1.00,2.00,"E","014ACI","976234","430","-","-","0",0.00,"-","STACY    ",11/4/2013,"00:21:16E","F","Y",8796.00,"PILOT 405","TIFTON","GA",3.77,3.77,172.65,650.73,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,650.73,1.50,0.00,652.23
"BRANCH","CARD","BILL_TYPE","AUTH_CODE","INVOICE","UNIT","EMP_NUM","TRIP","TRAILER","HUB/SPEED","VEH_LICENSE","DRIVER","DATE","TIME","CHAIN","IN_NETWORK","TS#","TS_NAME","TS_CITY","TS_STATE","PPG","NET_PPG","FUEL_GALS","FUEL_AMT","RFR_GALS","RFR_AMT","CASH","MISC","INV_TOTAL","FEE","DISC","INV_BALANCE",1.00,1.00,"E","004ACS","02812","365","-","-","0",0.00,"-","JOHN S  ",11/4/2013,"16:18:49E","IC","N",3257.00,"IRVING HOULTON","HOULTON","ME",3.95,3.95,121.57,480.08,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,480.08,1.50,0.00,481.58
"BRANCH","CARD","BILL_TYPE","AUTH_CODE","INVOICE","UNIT","EMP_NUM","TRIP","TRAILER","HUB/SPEED","VEH_LICENSE","DRIVER","DATE","TIME","CHAIN","IN_NETWORK","TS#","TS_NAME","TS_CITY","TS_STATE","PPG","NET_PPG","FUEL_GALS","FUEL_AMT","RFR_GALS","RFR_AMT","CASH","MISC","INV_TOTAL","FEE","DISC","INV_BALANCE",1.00,2.00,"E","014ACI","976234","430","-","-","0",0.00,"-","STACY    ",11/4/2013,"00:21:16E","F","Y",8796.00,"PILOT 405","TIFTON","GA",3.77,3.77,172.65,650.73,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,650.73,1.50,0.00,652.23
```

Every line starts with this duplicate text: `"BRANCH","CARD","BILL_TYPE","AUTH_CODE","INVOICE","UNIT","EMP_NUM","TRIP","TRAILER","HUB/SPEED","VEH_LICENSE","DRIVER","DATE","TIME","CHAIN","IN_NETWORK","TS#","TS_NAME","TS_CITY","TS_STATE","PPG","NET_PPG","FUEL_GALS","FUEL_AMT","RFR_GALS","RFR_AMT","CASH","MISC","INV_TOTAL","FEE","DISC","INV_BALANCE",`

***What I would like to do is...***

**OPTION 1:**

1. Put the duplicate text in a string
2. Remove the last char in the string
3. Remove all of the other duplicate text from the file using the string from no. 1
4. Save the .CSV file

**OPTION 2:**

1. Put the duplicate text in a string
2. Remove the last char in the string
3. Every loop/every line I would skip to column 305
4. Save the .CSV file

***How do I do this in classic-ASP?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A .ReadLine()/2 Files approach:

```
  Dim tsIn  : Set tsIn  = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\19936645.csv")
  Dim tsOut : Set tsOut = goFS.CreateTextFile("..\data\19936645-2.csv")
  Dim sFrs  : sFrs      = tsIn.ReadLine()
  Dim sLast : sLast     = """INV_BALANCE"","
  Dim nCutP : nCutP     = Instr(sFrs, sLast) + Len(sLast)
  Dim sHead : sHead     = Left(sFrs, nCutP - 2)
  Dim sLine
  tsOut.WriteLine sHead
  tsOut.WriteLine Mid(sFrs, nCutP)
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
     sLine = tsIn.ReadLine()
     If 1 = Instr(sLine, sHead) Then
        tsOut.WriteLine Mid(sLine, nCutP)
     Else
        WScript.Echo "Bingo!"
     End If
  Loop
  tsOut.Close
  tsIn.Close
```

that creates a new .csv with column header.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying Object required: ''  on this line:   Dim tsIn  : Set tsIn  = goFS.OpenTextFile("DATA\001a_1378532_1111.CSV")

Comment: @msvuze - you need a FileSystemObject (named goFS).