# Edit a CSV Record

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

How do I edit a record in a CSV file?

for example I have a .csv file named "test.csv" and inside it is:

```
"123","Active"
"456","Not-Active"
"999000123","Active"
```

How can I edit `"456"` and change it from `Not-Active` to `Active`

The only way I can think of it is to:

1. Open the .csv file. Maybe store the data inside a string?
2. Search for `"456","`.
3. Get the line position of `"456","`. How to do this?
4. Delete the line that we just got the position of. How to do this?
5. Recreate the line with what we want. How to do this?
6. Insert the recreated data in the line position. How to do this?
7. Save the .csv file.

But is there not a easier way to do this?

And if not how do I do steps # 4, 5, and 6?

Maybe to convert it onto an Array or something? But I have no idea how to do this in Classic ASP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open, Edit and Re-Save a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936645/open-edit-and-re-save-a-csv-file)

Comment: @abr No that was  to remove duplicate text but not to find text and then edit the text to the right of that text. Not the same or worse not a duplicate for sure

Comment: You read the file, split each line at commas, replace the value of the second field if the first field has the value `"456"`, then write the data back to the file.

Comment: Why not just convert your csv file into an mdb file (an Access database), you'd find it much easier to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Ekkehards answer, here is the ASP version. The .csv file needs to be located in the same directory as the .asp script. Feel free to award the points to Ekkehard

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>
<% option explicit %>

<%
Dim goFS  : Set goFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim tsIn  : Set tsIn  = goFS.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath( "46734115.csv"))
Dim tsOut : Set tsOut = goFS.CreateTextFile(Server.MapPath("46734115-2.csv"))
Dim sLine
Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
    sLine = tsIn.ReadLine()
    dim pos : pos = instr( sLine, """456"",")
    Response.Write(pos)
    if pos > 0 then 
      ' to keep things simple, just replace the whole line
      sLine = """456"",""Active"""
    end if
    tsOut.WriteLine sLine
    ' Just so there is something to see: print line to the browser window
    Response.Write( sLine & "<br />")
Loop
tsOut.Close
tsIn.Close
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simplyfied version of the [script @abr mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19937916/603855):

```
Dim goFS  : Set goFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim tsIn  : Set tsIn  = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\46734115.csv")
Dim tsOut : Set tsOut = goFS.CreateTextFile("..\data\46734115-2.csv")
Dim sLine
Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
    sLine = tsIn.ReadLine()
    WScript.Echo "<", sLine
    If "456," = Left(sLine, 4) Then
       sLine = "789,""something else"""
    End If
    WScript.Echo ">", sLine
    tsOut.WriteLine sLine
    WScript.Echo    
Loop
tsOut.Close
tsIn.Close
```

output:

```
type ..\data\46734115.csv
123,"Active"
456,"Not-Active"
999000123,"Active"

cscript 46734115-3.vbs
< 123,"Active"
> 123,"Active"

< 456,"Not-Active"
> 789,"something else"

< 999000123,"Active"
> 999000123,"Active"

type ..\data\46734115-2.csv
123,"Active"
789,"something else"
999000123,"Active"
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' Object required: 'WScript'. I tried adding WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") but that did not help

Comment: I tried replacing WScript.Echo with 'Response.write but that didnt work. Any input on what am I missing ?